# Bootstrap problem to open the modals on mobile device

Tags: bootstrap-modal

I have a table generated by a php cycle. each line has a button that opens a modal, on the PC it works perfectly. on mobile devices I have these problems.
1. When I load the page for the first time the browser does not allow me to click on the button that opens the modal. To unlock it, I must first click on any other button on the page (outside this table).
2. When I open the modal, the problem reappears after closing it. I have to click twice on any other button to be able to "unlock" again those of the table that open the modals.

I made several attempts, I also tried to delete all the other elements of the page to understand if the problem depended on something else but I didn't solve anything. Does anyone have any idea what it could be?

```
<?php

if(mysql_num_rows($result_optional) > 0){

echo "<div id='div_col_sx_custom'>
<form action='' method='get'>
<table border='0' cellpadding='10' cellspacing='0' width='100%' style='line-height:10px;'>";


while($row = mysql_fetch_array( $result_optional )) {


    echo "<tr>";
    echo '<td class="align-middle td_lista">
<input type="checkbox" class="selezionabile_" id="check-'.$idcheck.'" data-prezzo="'.$prezzocheck.'"  data-di-serie="false"  data-tipo="' . $tipocheck . '" data-nome="' . $titolocheck .'" >
<label for="check-'.$idcheck.'">' . $titolo_optional . '</label>
    </td>';

    echo '<td align="right" class="td_lista_right">
<div class="tasto_info" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#ModalCenter-'.$idcheck.'">&euro;&nbsp;<b>'.number_format($prezzocheck, 2 , ',' , '.').'</b>&nbsp;&nbsp;|&nbsp;&nbsp;+INFO</div>
</td>

    <!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="ModalCenter-'.$idcheck.'" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="ModalCenter-'.$idcheck.'" aria-hidden="true">
<div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered modal-lg" role="document">
<div class="modal-content modal-custom">
<div class="modal-header" style="border-color:transparent">
<h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLongTitle">'.$titolo_optional.'</h5>
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
              <span aria-hidden="true" class="close-modal-bt">&times;</span>
            </button>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-body">text</div>
          <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    ';


    echo "</tr>";
    }

    echo "</table></form></div>";

}

?>
```